# How to use HornetQ match patterns

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

I'm using Jboss 7.1.1.final and I need to define 2 different DLQ's so that one queue would have DLQ1 and the other queues  will have DLQ2.

I looked at HornetQ documentation and found the `address_settings` tag that have a `match` attribute:

```
<address-setting match="jms.queue.exampleQueue">
<dead-letter-address>jms.queue.deadLetterQueue</dead-letter-address>
```

If i have a queue defined like:

```
<jms-queue name="Test">
<entry name="queue/Test"/>
</jms-queue>
```

What would be the match pattern for it? is it jms.queue.Test?

How can i see the messages in the DLQ? Do i have to write an MDB that listens to it or is it possible to see it in the admin console of jboss?

Comment: can you please look into  it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692567/configuring-the-same-dead-letter-queue-for-several-jms-queues-in-jboss-7-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would be the match pattern for it? is it jms.queue.Test? -->> yes, that's correct pattern. You can use JMS browser API for this or hornetq admin API

Comment: There must be a technical reason, but it's very confusing that you need to add the "jms.queue." prefix to the queue name in the match attribute.