# Configuring the same dead letter queue for several JMS queues in JBoss 7.1

Tags: jms, jboss7.x, dead-letter

I have a java application running on JBoss 7.1. It is using more than 20 JMS-queues.

My configuration to setup the JMS queues:

```xml
<jms-queue name="MX.EQ.DT.MT.OUT">
   <entry name="queue/MX.EQ.DT.MT.OUT"/>
   <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/MX.EQ.DT.MT.OUT"/>
</jms-queue>

<jms-queue name="MX.EQ.DS.XML.OUT">
   <entry name="queue/MX.EQ.DS.XML.OUT"/>
   <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/MX.EQ.DS.XML.OUT"/>
</jms-queue>
```

Now, I want to configure the dead letter queue for above two queues. What value would I have to use for the match?

I can not use `#`, because it will be applicable to all JMS queues, but I only want the two.

```xml
<address-setting match="jms.queue.MX.EQ.*.*.OUT">
   <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
   <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
   <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
   <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
   <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
   <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
</address-setting>
```

Also is there anyway to push back the message from dead letter queue to originating queue?

I am using hornet queue version 2.2.13 and want to use the wild card as `MX.EQ.*.*.OUT`.
If I put `*` or `#` in between the characters, the server throws an exception during boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [Understanding the HornetQ Wildcard Syntax](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/wildcard-syntax.html):

> A HornetQ wildcard expression contains words delimited by the
>   character `'.'` (full stop).
>
> The special characters `'#'` and `'*'` also have special meaning and
>   can take the place of a word.
>   The character `'#'` means 'match any sequence of zero or more words'.
>   The character `'*'` means 'match a single word'.
>
> So the wildcard `'news.europe.#'` would match `'news.europe'`,
>   `'news.europe.sport'`, `'news.europe.politics'`, and
>   `'news.europe.politics.regional'` but would not match `'news.usa'`,
>   `'news.usa.sport'` nor `'entertainment'`.
>
> The wildcard `'news.*'` would match `'news.europe'`, but not
>   `'news.europe.sport'`.
>   The wildcard `'news.*.sport'` would match `'news.europe.sport'` and
>   also `'news.usa.sport'`, but not `'news.europe.politics'`.

In your configuration you could use the wilcard `*`, but in JBoss 7.1.1 the cofiguration parser throws a exception when you put a value with character `*`.

The error is similar to:

```
JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.PathElement$OperationClientIllegalArgumentException: JBAS014719: Invalid value specification
```

The same problem occurs when you use a space in the value, this problem is described in:
[Logger category cannot have spaces](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4206)

Now one option is update to JBoss 7.1.2 or higher, or create a different nomenclature for the name of queues, for example:

```
<jms-queue name="group1.q1">
    <entry name="queue/group1.q1"/>
    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/group1.q1"/>
</jms-queue>
<jms-queue name="group1.q2">
    <entry name="queue/group1.q2"/>
    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/group1.q2"/>
</jms-queue>
```

and `address-setting`:

```
<address-setting match="group1.#">
    <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
    <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
    <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
    <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
</address-setting>
```

The wilcard `#` only can be use at the end of the match.